# MS Access VBA: Fetch data from a query which corresponds to an ID field from a selected row in a subform table

Tags: vba, ms-access, field, dlookup

I'm completely new to VBA and MS Access!

- I have a Subform within a form which contains data about items which all have an "Equipment ID" field.
- Using data from a different table, I have a query to count the number of "faults" associated with each item. This Query also has the "Equipment ID" field.
- I have a second form which contains text boxes, and can be accessed by a button. On the button click, the form opens up and data from the selected current row in the subform are passed into the text boxes. I have assigned the original data table to the form control source.

What I want to do:

- I'm having trouble with the query. I have been trying to link the subform and the query, so that when the row on the sub form is selected, the "Equipment ID" is grabbed from that, and the "number of faults" in the Query can be found from its corresponding "Equipment ID".

Here is the code so far (and what I want to happen in comments):

```
Private Sub Button_Click()  

 Dim db As Database 
 Dim rs As DAO.Recordset 
 Dim EqIDfrm As String  'Equipment ID from the subform    
 
 'Open up the Faults Query    
 Set db = CurrentDb
 Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("qryFaultTotal") 

 'open up the second form  
 DoCmd.OpenForm "SecondForm"    

 'Grab the "Year" from the selected row in the sub form and assign it to SelectYear. The text   
 'box value in the second form then becomes the SelectYear value.      
 SelectYear = [Forms]![Form1]![tblAsset Subform].[Form]![Year]  
 [Forms]![Form2]![txtYear] = SelectYear    
 ' etc. for other fields  

'grab the equipment ID from the subform and from the Query  
EqIDfrm = [Forms]![Form1]![tblAsset Subform].[Form]![Equipment_ID]      
EqIDqry = rs![Equipment_ID] 
'<--- this seems to be part of the problem  

'Lookup the Total number of faults from the FaultTotal Query, where the Equipment ID in the Query is   
 the same as the equipment ID on the subform from the selected row.   
 
Fault = DLookup("[TotalFault]", "[FaultTotal]", "[EqIDqry] = " & [EqIDfrm] & "")  


End Sub
```

- When I use lookup I keep getting an error of some sort (type mismatch, run-time error), and I just can't figure it out. It doesn't seem to like the EqIDqry but I don't know why despite Googling. I feel like it should be very simple, but I understand I may have to do something totally different! Any advice would be appreciated :)

Comment: Referencing a variable within quote marks accomplishes nothing. Instead of [EqIDqry], must reference field name that is in table or query - presumably that is Equipment_ID. Recordset object has no relevance to this DLookup(). Concatenating `""` is not necessary.

Comment: Could just have DLookup() expression in textbox - no need for VBA. Why do you need code to populate textboxes? Why not bound form and bound controls? Apply filter to form.

Comment: Hi there, not to worry thanks, I got it working now! I had tried Dlookup previously but it wasn't working for me at the time, so I tried it again and that seems to work now!